# Humble pack on steam and future releases

Tags: steam, humble-bundle

I bought the humble pack #2 and activated it through Steam. However, only 3 games were available through that platform at the moment.

Does anybody know how the key works for the pack? Assuming one of the games in it gets released in Steam in the future, will it automatically be associated to my account?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the more info link on http://www.humblebundle.com/

> On your download page, you can
>   optionally get a key to redeem your
>   Humble Bundle #2 games (first shelf)
>   on Steam and / or Desura. Not all of
>   the games are on Steam yet: Cortex
>   Command and Revenge of the Titans **will
>   automatically be added to your library
>   once they make their Steam debut.**

Comment: Thanks, I should have read more carefully (although users don't read)